# how can I use a source column for dynamically partitioning the data in target data lake in azure data factory Copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using the ADF copy activity and source is SQL server.

Now I may decide to pull whole data or incremental data based on a date field - so when I do that - I wan to create/overwrite the folders in my data lake based on this column.

**Source data:**

col1

Col2

Col3
FilterColumn(Date)

**Target Lake:**

e.g. If I pull 1 year of data - the folder structure in lake should be created as below (based on FilterColumn):

entity/2020/03/01/abc.csv

entity/2020/03/02/abc.csv

entity/2020/03/03/abc.csv

entity/2020/03/04/abc.csv

..

..

entity/2021/02/28/abc.csv

where folders are created dynamically based on source filter column - also coming in as a part of the select query.

Suggestions on how can I achieve this within the same copy activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can't be achieved with only one copy activity. You can do this by Lookup activity and For Each activity.

Steps:

1. use Lookup activity to get distinct col3 value and change format to yy/mm/dd.

[image]

2. loop Lookup activity's output by For Each activity.

[image]

3. copy different date data to corresponding CSV file within For Each activity.

Source:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Sink dataset:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steve.. even I came to the same conclusion.. will try this